# Unable to update the setState in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on the Weather application Using React. Where I am using Mapbox API to fetch the lat and long of the given location. I am not being able to update the state, where I need to update the lat and long of the given location.

can anyone please help me to find out the mistake in my code?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Display.css'
import Individual from '../../Container/Individual/Individual'
import axios from 'axios'

class Display extends Component {
  state ={
    details:{
      address:'Melbourne',
      latitude:'',
      longitude:''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const URL = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${this.state.details.address}.json?access_token=pk.MYAPI_KEY`

    axios.get(URL)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data.features[0].center)
      this.setState({
        latitude:res.data.features[0].center[0],
        longitude:res.data.features[0].center[1]
      })
    })

    console.log(this.state)
  }






  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Display'>
        <Individual 
        location={this.state.details.address} 
        latitude={this.state.details.latitude} 
        longitude={this.state.details.longitude}  />
        {/* <Individual />
        <Individual />
        <Individual />
        <Individual />
        <Individual /> */}

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Display
```

Result in console
`details: {address: "Melbourne", latitude: "", longitude: ""}`

can anyone tell me Why my state is not updating?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking why in console you getting

```
details: {address: "Melbourne", latitude: "", longitude: ""}
```

Its because the **axios** call is **asynchronous**, and the console.log is triggered before axios finish, even when you put it after the **axios** call. Yes that's how Javascript do.

To actually know if your state is updating or not , put `console.log` right after `this.setState`, in the `then` promise

```
axios.get(URL)
.then(res=>{
  console.log(res.data.features[0].center)
  this.setState({
    latitude:res.data.features[0].center[0],
    longitude:res.data.features[0].center[1]
  })
  console.log(this.state) // it should already updated here
})
```

Comment: So how can pass that updated state through the props?

Comment: You could use componentDidUpdate in order to access the new state [have a look here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)